# Power shell - Send email every 1 min until input is provided

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to work on a power shell script which can do the following:

**- keep sending email every 1 minute until a input of "Y" or "y" is given**

If the user enters anything other than "Y" or "y", it will return back to the input screen immediately. It will keep going to the input screen until "Y" or "y" is entered.
If the user enters "Y" or "y", the script exits.
An email is triggered to the user every 1 minute while the script has not exited.

The catch here is not to make the user wait for 1 minute for the next input to be taken. The next input should be immediate if "Y" or "y" is not entered. Only the email is to be sent every 1 minute until the script exits.

Example

```
Enter "Y" to exit alert >>: n
Enter "Y" to exit alert >>: g
Enter "Y" to exit alert >>: h
Enter "Y" to exit alert >>: d
Enter "Y" to exit alert >>: 
Enter "Y" to exit alert >>: r
Enter "Y" to exit alert >>: y
Exited
```

Thanks

Comment: nice, so can you show us where you're struggling with your code?

Comment: Try `Read-Host` and `Start-Sleep`.

Comment: We have used Read-Host and Start-Sleep in a while loop. The problem is the Read-Host input is also part of the sleep. We do not want the input to go into a sleep. Sleep should just be for sending emails every 1 minute. Both input and sending emails should work simultaneously. Only email is triggered every 1 minute via sleep but input is taken anytime. I cant seem to work out the code for this.